# Accessing private variables of a class C++

Tags: c++

Trying to overload the == operator, want to compare the hour, min, sec variables, but they're declared private and we've been told we're not allowed to adjust the header file. How do I access them in my code that is overloading the == operator? I also can't access them as h, m, s as they're called in the setTime method.

```
// using _TIMEX_H_ since _TIME_H_ seems to be used by some C++ systems

#ifndef _TIMEX_H_
#define _TIMEX_H_

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

class Time
{ public:
    Time();
    Time(int h, int m = 0, int s = 0);
    void setTime(int, int, int);
    Time operator+(unsigned int) const;
    Time& operator+=(unsigned int);
    Time& operator++();    // postfix version
    Time operator++(int);  // prefix version

    // new member functions that you have to implement

    Time operator-(unsigned int) const;
    Time& operator-=(unsigned int);
    Time& operator--();      // postfix version
    Time operator--(int);  // prefix version

    bool operator==(const Time&) const;
    bool operator<(const Time&) const;
    bool operator>(const Time&) const;

  private:
    int hour, min, sec;

  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Time&);

  // new friend functions that you have to implement

  friend bool operator<=(const Time&, const Time&);
  friend bool operator>=(const Time&, const Time&);
  friend bool operator!=(const Time&, const Time&);

  friend unsigned int operator-(const Time&, const Time&);
};

#endif
```

.cpp file

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Time.h"

Time::Time()
{ hour = min = sec = 0;
}

Time::Time(int h, int m, int s)
{ setTime(h, m, s);
}

void Time::setTime(int h, int m, int s)
{ hour = (h>=0 && h<24) ? h : 0;
  min = (m>=0 && m<60) ? m : 0;
  sec = (s>=0 && s<60) ? s : 0;
}

Time operator==(Time &t1, Time &t2)
{
    return (t1.hour==t2.hour);
}
```

Comment: `Time Time::operator==(Time &t1, Time &t2)` would do. You're missing something.

Comment: Your `operator ==` in the h file and in the cpp file are not the same. You should adjust the cpp file to your h file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `==` operator you're supposed to implement is a member function, so you should define

```
bool Time::operator==(const Time& t) const
{
    return hour == t.hour && min == t.min && sec == t.sec;
}
```

Comment: how can you access t.hour ?

Comment: It's a member function. You write "t.hour".

Comment: So you can say this->hour but you can't say t.hour. Assume that i overload == operator for some other class. Can i access their private variables?

Comment: @cokceken You can access private members of other instances of the same class.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I compare values if I'm only declaring t in this function?

Comment: You guys are right, i thought member functions can only access defined class instance's private fields.

Comment: @Chaz It's a regular member function, and `*this` is the left-hand operand. (I added the relevant code.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick:

```
bool operator==(Time &t1, Time &t2)
{
    return !(t1 != t2);
}
bool operator!=(const Time& t1, const Time& t2)
{
    return t1.hour != t2.hour || t1.min != t2.min || t1.sec != t2.sec;
}
```

You can't access your private fields in your operator== function. But since your operator!= is defined as friend, you can do it there.

Comment: you cant access t2.hour it is private

Comment: Yes, you can't access it in the function operator==  but you can access it in the function operator!=

Comment: There is no need to implement a non-member `operator ==` - there is already a member `operator ==`.  The whole header file is badly designed.  `operator ==`, and `operator <` should be non-member friends.  All the other comparisons should be non-members defined in terms of these two, and don't need to be friends.  Eg: `operator >` returns `rhs < lhs`, and `operator <=` returns `!(rhs < lhs)`.